# Implementing a "cautious" take_while using Peekable

Tags: iterator, rust, traits, borrow-checker

I'd like to use `Peekable` as the basis for a new `cautious_take_while` operation that acts like  `take_while` from `IteratorExt` but without consuming the first failed item. (There's a side question of whether this is a good idea, and whether there are better ways to accomplish this goal in Rust -- I'd be happy for hints in that direction, but mostly I'm trying to understand where my code is breaking).

The API I'm trying to enable is basically:

```
let mut chars = "abcdefg.".chars().peekable();

let abc : String = chars.by_ref().cautious_take_while(|&x| x != 'd');
let defg : String = chars.by_ref().cautious_take_while(|&x| x != '.');

// yielding (abc = "abc", defg = "defg")
```

I've taken a crack at [creating a MCVE here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=extern%20crate%20core%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aiter%3A%3APeekable%3B%0Ause%20core%3A%3Astr%3A%3AChars%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20chars%20%3D%20%22test%22.chars().peekable()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20%22take_while%22%20works...%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%20chars.by_ref().take_while(%7C%26x%7C%20x%20!%3D%20%27.%27)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20..%20but%20%22cautious_take_while%22%20fails%0A%20%20%20%20chars.by_ref().cautious_take_while(%7C%26x%7C%20x%20!%3D%20%27.%27)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23%5Bderive(Clone)%5D%0Astruct%20CautiousTakeWhile%3CT%3A%20Iterator%2C%20P%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20inner%3A%20T%2C%0A%20%20%20%20condition%3A%20P%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3CT%3A%20Iterator%2C%20P%3E%20Iterator%20for%20CautiousTakeWhile%3CPeekable%3CT%3E%2C%20P%3E%0Awhere%20P%3A%20FnMut(%26T%3A%3AItem)%20-%3E%20bool%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Item%20%3D%20T%3A%3AItem%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20next(%26mut%20self)%20-%3E%20Option%3CT%3A%3AItem%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20return_next%20%3D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20self.inner.peek()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Some(ref%20v)%20%3D%3E%20(self.condition)(v)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%3E%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20return_next%20%7B%20self.inner.next()%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20None%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Atrait%20CautiousTakeWhileable%3A%20Iterator%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20cautious_take_while%3CP%3E(self%2C%20P)%20-%3E%20CautiousTakeWhile%3CSelf%2C%20P%3E%20where%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20P%3A%20FnMut(%26Self%3A%3AItem)%20-%3E%20bool%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20%3CT%3A%20Iterator%3E%20CautiousTakeWhileable%20for%20Peekable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20cautious_take_while%3CP%3E(self%2C%20f%3A%20P)%20-%3E%20CautiousTakeWhile%3CPeekable%3CT%3E%2C%20P%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20where%20P%3A%20FnMut(%26T%3A%3AItem)%20-%3E%20bool%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CautiousTakeWhile%7Binner%3A%20self%2C%20condition%3A%20f%2C%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A), but I'm getting:

> :10:5: 10:19 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
> :10     chars.by_ref().cautious_take_while(|&x| x != '.');

As far as I can tell, I'm following the same pattern as Rust's own `TakeWhile` in terms of my function signatures, but I'm seeing different different behavior from the borrow checker. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The funny thing with `by_ref()` is that it returns a mutable reference to itself:

```
pub trait IteratorExt: Iterator + Sized {
    fn by_ref(&mut self) -> &mut Self { self }
}
```

It works because the `Iterator` trait is implemented for the *mutable pointer to Iterator* type. Smart!

```
impl<'a, I> Iterator for &'a mut I where I: Iterator, I: ?Sized { ... }
```

The standard `take_while` function works because it uses the trait `Iterator`, that is automatically resolved to `&mut Peekable<T>`.

But your  code does not work because `Peekable` is a struct, not a trait, so your `CautiousTakeWhileable` must specify the type, and you are trying to take ownership of it, but you cannot, because you have a mutable pointer.

Solution, do not take a `Peekable<T>` but `&mut Peekable<T>`. You will need to specify the lifetime too:

```
impl <'a, T: Iterator, P> Iterator for CautiousTakeWhile<&'a mut Peekable<T>, P>
where P: FnMut(&T::Item) -> bool {
     //...
}

impl <'a, T: Iterator> CautiousTakeWhileable for &'a mut Peekable<T> {
    fn cautious_take_while<P>(self, f: P) -> CautiousTakeWhile<&'a mut Peekable<T>, P>
     where P: FnMut(&T::Item) -> bool {
        CautiousTakeWhile{inner: self, condition: f,}
    }
}
```

A curious side effect of this solution is that now `by_ref` is not needed, because `cautious_take_while()` takes a mutable reference, so it does not steal ownership. The `by_ref()` call is needed for `take_while()` because it can take either `Peekable<T>` or `&mut Peekable<T>`, and it defaults to the first one. With the `by_ref()` call it will resolve to the second one.

And now that I finally understand it, I think it might be a good idea to change the definition of `struct CautiousTakeWhile` to include the peekable bit into the struct itself. The difficulty is that the lifetime has to be specified manually, if I'm right. Something like:

```
struct CautiousTakeWhile<'a, T: Iterator + 'a, P> 
    where T::Item : 'a {
    inner: &'a mut Peekable<T>,
    condition: P,
}
trait CautiousTakeWhileable<'a, T>: Iterator {
    fn cautious_take_while<P>(self, P) -> CautiousTakeWhile<'a, T, P> where
        P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool;
}
```

and the rest is more or less straightforward.

Comment: Thanks @rodrigo! I've incorporated your first suggestion to produce a working example at http://is.gd/NalTYL. But when I try to bring the typing into the struct, as in  http://is.gd/6c64vf, I get `error: the trait *core::clone::Clone* is not implemented for the type *&mut core::iter::Peekable<T>*`, which I can't seem to overcome by adding `+ Clone` to the trait bounds in line 43.

Comment: @Bosh. Not sure, but I think that a mutable pointer cannot be cloned. Your variant accepts the `Clone` probably because `Peekable` implents `Clone` explicitly. Maybe you can do the same, but the code would need some refactoring...

Comment: Great. I stopped deriving from `Clone` and cleaned up timelines:  http://is.gd/ljjJAE .  Thanks again for your help + explanations!

Comment: @Bosh: Glad to help, I learned a lot too. It looks that your original version accepted the `#[derive(clone]` because for parametric types the compiler accepts the directive if it cannot prove that it will never work. But then, it may silently fail to do so in a specific type. For example `#derive(Clone)] struct X<T>(T);` will compile, but the actual `X::clone()` will be available only if `T` is clonable.

Answer (score 1):

This was a tricky one! I'll lead with the meat of the code, then attempt to explain it (if I understand it...). It's also the ugly, unsugared version, as I wanted to reduce incidental complexity.

```
use std::iter::Peekable;

fn main() {
    let mut chars = "abcdefg.".chars().peekable();

    let abc: String = CautiousTakeWhile{inner: chars.by_ref(), condition: |&x| x != 'd'}.collect();
    let defg: String = CautiousTakeWhile{inner: chars.by_ref(), condition: |&x| x != '.'}.collect();
    println!("{}, {}", abc, defg);
}

struct CautiousTakeWhile<'a, I, P> //'
    where I::Item: 'a, //'
          I: Iterator + 'a, //'
          P: FnMut(&I::Item) -> bool,
{
    inner: &'a mut Peekable<I>, //'
    condition: P,
}

impl<'a, I, P> Iterator for CautiousTakeWhile<'a, I, P>
    where I::Item: 'a, //'
          I: Iterator + 'a, //'
          P: FnMut(&I::Item) -> bool
{
    type Item = I::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I::Item> {
        let return_next =
            match self.inner.peek() {
                Some(ref v) => (self.condition)(v),
                _ => false,
            };
        if return_next { self.inner.next() } else { None }
    }
}
```

Actually, [Rodrigo seems to have a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28777216/155423), so I'll defer to that, unless you'd like me to explain something specific.