# Consume parts of a string while iterating over it

Tags: rust

I am trying to parse a particular string which has format similar to this:

```
prefix,body1:body2
```

I would like to use `.chars` method and other methods like `.take_while` and others like this:

```
let chars = str.chars();
let prefix: String = chars.take_while(|&c| c != ',').collect();
let body1: String = chars.take_while(|&c| c != ':').collect();
let body2: String = chars.take_while(|_| true).collect();
```

([Playground](http://is.gd/M6krE5))

But the compiler complains:

```
error: use of moved value: `chars` [E0382]
     let body1: String = chars.take_while(|&c| c != ':').collect();
                         ^~~~~
help: see the detailed explanation for E0382
note: `chars` moved here because it has type `core::str::Chars<'_>`, which is non-copyable
     let prefix: String = chars.take_while(|&c| c != ',').collect();
                                  ^~~~~
```

I can rewrite it to a plain `for` loop and accumulate the value, but this is something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably simplest to just `split` the string on the delimiters:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "prefix,body1:body2";
    let parts: Vec<_> = s.split(|c| c == ',' || c == ':').collect();
    println!("{:?}", parts);
}
```

However, if you want to use the iterators, you can avoid consuming the `Chars` iterator by taking a mutable reference to it with [`Iterator::by_ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref):

```
let str = "prefix,body1:body2";
let mut chars = str.chars();
let prefix: String = chars.by_ref().take_while(|&c| c != ',').collect();
let body1: String = chars.by_ref().take_while(|&c| c != ':').collect();
let body2: String = chars.take_while(|_| true).collect();
```

For more info on `by_ref`, see:

- [Why does Iterator::take_while take ownership of the iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31374051/155423)
- [Implementing a "cautious" take_while using Peekable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28776630/155423).

Comment: Nice! But personally, I always forget that there are methods like `by_ref`, `as_mut` and such which do all that Rust magic.

Comment: @franza, also `take_while(|_| true)` is unnecessary, you can just as well call `collect()` directly.