# Multiple self borrows

Tags: rust, borrowing

I'm learning Rust and am trying to write a simple lexer. I have a function `next_token` in an `impl` block that reads the next token from an input character iterator. However, the code will not build because of multiple borrows of self. How do I get around this?

```
struct Lexer<'a> {
    input: Peekable<Chars<'a>>
}

...

impl<'a> Lexer<'a> {
    pub fn create(input: &str) -> Lexer {
        Lexer { input: input.chars().peekable() }
    }

    fn next_token(&mut self) -> Option<Token> {
        match self.input.by_ref().peek() {
            Some(c) if c.is_alphabetic() || *c == '_' => { // Identifier or keyword
                let literal = self.input.take_while(|&ch| {
                    match self.input.peek() {
                        Some(inner_c) => inner_c.is_alphanumeric() || *inner_c == '_',
                        None => false
                    }
                }).collect::<String>();
                if let Some(keyword) = check_keyword(&literal) { // Literal is a keyword
                    return Some(Token { literal: literal, token_type: keyword });
                } else { // Literal is identifier
                    return Some(Token { literal: literal, token_type: TokenType::Identifier });
                };
            },
            ... // Other cases
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting:

> error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content    -->
>   lexer.rs:110:20
>       | 110 |                                   let literal = self.input.take_while(|&ch| {
>       |                                                 ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
>
> error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `self` but
>   `self.input` is already borrowed    --> lexer.rs:110:42
>       | 108 |                   match self.input.by_ref().peek() {
>       |                         ---------- borrow occurs here 109 |                           Some(c) if c.is_alphabetic() || *c == '_' => { // Identifier or
>   keyword 110 |                                   let literal =
>   self.input.take_while(|&ch| {
>       |                                                         ^^^^^ closure construction occurs here 111 |
>   match self.input.peek() {
>       |                            ---- borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure ... 139 |                   }
>       |                   - borrow ends here

Comment: Can't find appropriate duplicate at the moment, but it exists. Split up your type into more fine-grained types and move the methods to those. Then you can call `self.thing1.fn1(...)` `self.thing2.fn2(...)`.

Comment: Can I do that if I'm referencing self.input in both locations?

Comment: Have to see code to be sure, but I believe so. If you do `self.thing1.fn(self.input)` and `self.thing2.fn(self.input)`, for example. Short version is that borrow checking stops at the function boundary. Inside one function, it can see that `self.thing1` and `self.input` are disjoint, but if you borrow `self.input` in one function and call another method on `self, then it assumes that method could do anything, including invalidate your mutable reference.

Comment: You can circumvent your specific problem by using a [more cautious take_while](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776630/implementing-a-cautious-take-while-using-peekable)

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that's what I need.